# Kubernetes service per pod of type NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I want to use service per pod, but I didn't found how to run service per pod of type nodePort.

I was trying to use that, but every service is created of type ClusterIP
https://github.com/metacontroller/metacontroller/tree/master/examples/service-per-pod

I need to create pod together with service of type nodePort.

Current configuration

````
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    service-per-pod-label: "statefulset.kubernetes.io/nginx"
    service-per-pod-ports: "80:80"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  serviceName: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

`ClusterIP` is the default type. Define the type `NodePort` in the spec section if you want to use that.

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Where to put that? I linked into answer my current configuration, I'm not defining service anywhere, to get service per pod, only annotation.

Comment: Add it [here](https://github.com/metacontroller/metacontroller/blob/master/examples/service-per-pod/manifest/service-per-pod.yaml) to the service yaml at the bottom.

Comment: Added it, still cluster ip is being created. 
ONLY in metacontroller namespace I observerd that type of service nodeport was changed, however it looks like it's not related.